Is there a way to speed up vectorized log operations in scipy optimize?
I'm doing some optimization in which I am calculating the $ amount needed to get the change in conversion using elasticities.  Originally, I used simple elasticities but am thinking of converting to compounding elasticities.  However, just doing this simple switch has increased the time it takes for me to optimize dramatically, I'm talking about like from 3 minutes to like days.
Simple Elasticity:
(ChangeInConversion * 100 / Elasticity) * -1

Compounding Elasticity:
(np.log(1 + ChangeInConversion ) / np.log(1 + Elasticity)) * 100 * -1 

Are there ways to speed things up, or is this an expected behavior if you start using logs in your optimization functions?  I'm using the Scipy Optimize package.  Both ChangeInConversion and Elasticity are vectors of values (np.arrays).
Thanks!
Edit: The function I am using is:
def FDollarChange(OptimizedUnitCount): 
    _OptimizedUnitCount = np.array(OptimizedUnitCount)
    _OptimizedUnitCountByChannel = np.dot(ChannelMatrix.toarray(), _OptimizedUnitCount)
    _ChangeInUnitCountByChannel = _OptimizedUnitCountByChannel - CurrentUnitCountByChannel
    ChangeInConversion  = _ChangeInUnitCountByChannel / CurrentUnitCountByChannel

    # expand out to full rows
    ChangeInConversion  = np.dot(ChannelMatrixT.toarray(), ChangeInConversion)
    DollarChange = (ChangeInConversion * 100 / Elasticity) * -1 # simple method
    # DollarChange = (np.log(1 + ChangeInConversion) / np.log(1 + Elasticity)) * 100 * -1 # compounding method
    
    return DollarChange, ChangeInConversion

def FTotalProfit(OptimizedUnitCount):
    _OptimizedUnitCount = np.array(OptimizedUnitCount)
    _DollarChange, _ChangeInConversion = FDollarChange(OptimizedUnitCount)
    PostProfit = PreProfit + _DollarChange
    TotalProfit = np.dot(_OptimizedUnitCount, TotalProfit)

    return PostProfit, TotalProfit

def ObjectiveFunction(OptimizedUnitCount):
    _OptimizedUnitCount = np.array(OptimizedUnitCount)
    _PostProfit, _TotalProfit = FTotalProfit(_OptimizedUnitCount)

    return (_TotalProfit * -1)

Where:

OptimizedUnitCount: Is basically the x values in the optimizer.
ChannelMatrix: Is basically a sparse matrix that does a group by    sum allowing me to calculate a grouped by OptimizedUnitCount
ChannelMatrixT: Is ChannelMatrix transposed that converts things    back to the original vector size.


log may not vectorise very well in general. There may be a log1px or something similar to save the 1+x. AOTBE I'd have expected a hit of around 60-100x slower for using log twice with possibly an extra factor of however many values can parallelised.  There may be ways to speed things up a lot if you can give assurances about the magnitudes of "change" and "elasticity". Please clarify the expected range of values that they can take.

Elasticities can only take two values 3% and 8% depending on channel, but the change in conversion is basically unbounded as I'm trying to optimize how much we should sell products in different channels.  Basically I'm trying to maximize profits, and then the elasticities is used to calculate how much more/less we'd make if we change prices.

If elasticity can only take one of two values then fold it into the constant *100. If the other value is literally unbounded then no fast tricks are available. But if you can live with -0.5 to 1 then x*(6+x)/(6+4x) is a fast Pade approximation to log(1+x) to ~1%. Others are possible and more accurate but you have to accept some boundaries first.

@MartinBrown Are you sure? The two functions seem very different (see here). Maybe you miss the initial factor? This one seems far better: 0.43x*((6+x)/(6+4x)) (in the [-0.5;1] range)

When converting between non-logged and logged expressions, it seems like np.log(x / y) ought to become np.log(x) - np.log(y) It seems like if you divide the logs, then you are basically computing x ** (1/log(y)). Is using division here intentional?

@JeromeRichard yes certain. It is the natural log in base e rather than log10(1+x). log(1+1) = 7/10 and log (1-1/2) = -11/16 = -0.6875. The true values should be +/- 0.69315 to 5 sig fig. Is np.log implicitly base 10? Your 0.43 is 1/log(10) aka 1/2.303.

@NickODell I'm pretty sure I have it the right way.  Reason being is because I'm not calculating a pct change, which you could do with np.log(x / y) but I already have the pct change and want to translate it a $ price change needed to get to that change in quantity.  I've compared the $ amounts using the two formulas and they are similar.

@MartinBrown Indeed, in the software I used (Geogebra), log is the log base 10 and I forgot np.log is the natural logarithm too so I was confused (sad it is not np.ln like in math). Sorry. My bad.

How big are the vectors? Are operations done in simple-precision or double one already? And if this is double-precision, then can't you use simple-precision (which is faster) instead? After all, this is an optimization process so results will not be exact anyway.

@JérômeRichard I haven't looked into whether or not it's simple or double precision.  The vector as of now is upwards of 450 values, but can increase depending on the business needs.  Let me see if I can convert all the input data to simple precision before optimizing.

Ok. Then using the SVML is the best solution on x86-64 CPUs. Simple precision (SP) is 3x faster on my machine. SVML should make this a bit faster on SP-based arrays. See this post. Approximations not bring a significant improvement since ~40% of the time is already spent in Numpy arrays for np.log in SP on my machine. Numba can help too like in the post (but not multiple threads here).

"3 minutes to days" means 24*20 = 480x slowdown (at least). I can't reproduce such slowdown by substituting those two lines of code.

@dankal444 I updated with the full function.

@we_are_all_in_this_together could you create reproducible example with timings? Added code makes it even less probable that such big slowdown should occur only by switching this one line.

@dankal444 Ok let me add the other functions.

@MartinBrown The ChangeInConversion does have some indirect 'bounds' because I have some other constraints, but no direct bounds.  I guess I could set some direct bounds since we probably won't be able to double conversion realistically - so maybe that will help too.

Try the substitution for log(1+x)  I suggested earlier  (but bear in mind that it is really only good to 1% over the range -0.5 to 1 and see how slow that is. I can believe that log is slow on vector code but you slowdown seems way too much to me. That will give you another data point between the simplest form and the other (rather weird function). I don't understand the reason for that function being reasonable in this application so I am assuming that it actually does what you want.

@we_are_all_in_this_together I meant minimal, reproducible example. Adding new code is something opposite to "minimal" aspect :) Well just prove to us and yourself that changing this one line gives so much slow down.


However, just doing this simple switch has increased the time it takes for me to optimize dramatically, I'm talking about like from 3 minutes to like days.

I don't think that could be caused solely by np.log() being slow. I benchmarked both approaches:
(ChangeInConversion * 100 / Elasticity) * -1
6.94 µs ± 48.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
(np.log(1 + ChangeInConversion ) / np.log(1 + Elasticity)) * 100 * -1
27.7 µs ± 31.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

This is only a 4x difference, and that's making the assumption that the rest of your objective function takes zero time. It can't account for a ~1000x difference.

Are there ways to speed things up, or is this an expected behavior if you start using logs in your optimization functions?

It's pretty common advice to give that if you're having trouble optimizing a function, then you can try re-parameterizing the function. For example, instead of optimizing f(x), optimize f(log(x)) or f(e**x). The optimizer can end up running faster or slower if you do this.
Here's a somewhat contrived example. Imagine you're trying to optimize the following function:
import scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, minimize


def negative_ten_expected_logged(x):
    return np.sum((10 + np.log(x))**2)

This function has a minimum value of 0 when every element of the function equals e-10.
Let's optimize the function, with a strange initial guess:
x0 = np.exp(np.linspace(0, -100, 1000))
result = minimize(
    negative_ten_expected_logged,
    x0=x0,
    method='L-BFGS-B',
    bounds=Bounds(lb=1e-50),
    options=dict(maxfun=1e7)
)
result

Result:
  message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
  success: True
   status: 0
      fun: 1.210443420820441e-05
        x: [ 4.539e-05  4.540e-05 ...  4.539e-05  4.539e-05]
      nit: 313
      jac: [-1.646e+00  6.396e-01 ... -2.572e-03 -2.566e-03]
     nfev: 859859
     njev: 859
 hess_inv: <1000x1000 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
35.1 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

Let's try a change of coordinates. Rather than try to optimize f(x), we'll try to optimize f(e**x).
def negative_ten_expected(x):
    return negative_ten_expected_logged(np.exp(x))

Let's try optimizing it:
x0 = np.linspace(0, -100, 1000)
result = minimize(
    negative_ten_expected,
    x0=x0,
    method='L-BFGS-B',
    bounds=Bounds(lb=np.log(1e-50)),
    options=dict(maxfun=1e7)
)
result

Result:
  message: CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL
  success: True
   status: 0
      fun: 2.4761268292778848e-14
        x: [-1.000e+01 -1.000e+01 ... -1.000e+01 -1.000e+01]
      nit: 4
      jac: [-1.523e-10 -1.988e-10 ... -3.250e-10  7.641e-10]
     nfev: 9009
     njev: 9
 hess_inv: <1000x1000 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
432 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

That's about 100x faster! This speedup didn't come from doing fewer operations, either. We're doing np.log(np.exp(x)), which is slower than np.log(x), even if the two cancel out algebraically. The speedup came from having a function where the slopes change in a more predictable fashion.
In summary, this shows that optimizing f(log(x)) can be much much slower than optimizing f(x), depending on the function.
The other possibility is that numeric differentiation provides an inaccurate answer when applied to your logged function. Without a runnable example, it is hard to say.

Very insightful! As I was expecting, logarithm itself is not a problem. Good you looked at the problem from a wider perspective.
